# Select multiple tuples into one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT contact_id, name, email, phone, city 
FROM ak_contact
WHERE email = 'test@gmail.com'
ORDER BY contact_id DESC
```

Tis query returns me something like this:

```
contact_id  name       email     phone      city

  8499  Serj    test@gmail.com      
  8498  Serj    test@gmail.com  3-33-333    
  8494  Serj    test@gmail.com              London
  8493  Serj    test@gmail.com  2-22-222
```

But I need one tuple as a result containing only latest values ( if they are not null/empty )
So the result I need should looks like this:

```
  contact_id name   email           phone       city

      8499  Serj    test@gmail.com  3-33-333    London
```

Comment: so what do you mean by `LATEST`? how can you tell that the record is the latest among the group?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by latest? Or even expand your data set, show the full table structure.

Comment: Guys, if you can't get the sense of the question it's not the reason to vote against it. It's not my fault that the database has the stupid structure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not generally a fan of nested `select` statements, but that is one way to approach this in MySQL:

```
select (select contact_id
        from ak_contact
        where email = 'test@gmail.com' and
              contact_id is not null
        order by contact_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as contact_id,
       (select name
        from ak_contact
        where email = 'test@gmail.com' and
              name is not null
        order by contact_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as name,
       (select phone
        from ak_contact
        where email = 'test@gmail.com' and
              phone is not null
        order by contact_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as phone,
       (select city
        from ak_contact
        where email = 'test@gmail.com' and
              city is not null
        order by contact_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as city
```

Each column might be coming from a different row, so each gets its own query.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but it looks very scary ))
In this case foreach on php will be better

Answer (score 3):

More along the lines of Gordon's answer...

```
SELECT a.c_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.name IS NULL THEN (SELECT name 
                                   FROM   ak_contact 
                                   WHERE  name IS NOT NULL 
                                          AND email = a.email 
                                   ORDER  BY c_id DESC 
                                   LIMIT  1) 
         ELSE b.name 
       end AS name, 
       b.email, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.phone IS NULL THEN (SELECT phone 
                                    FROM   ak_contact 
                                    WHERE  phone IS NOT NULL 
                                           AND email = a.email 
                                    ORDER  BY c_id DESC 
                                    LIMIT  1) 
         ELSE b.phone 
       end AS phone, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.city IS NULL THEN (SELECT city 
                                   FROM   ak_contact 
                                   WHERE  city IS NOT NULL 
                                          AND email = a.email 
                                   ORDER  BY c_id DESC 
                                   LIMIT  1) 
         ELSE b.city 
       end AS city 
FROM   (SELECT email, 
               Max(c_id) AS c_id 
        FROM   ak_contact 
        WHERE  email = 'test@gmail.com' 
        GROUP  BY email) a 
       LEFT JOIN ak_contact b 
              ON b.c_id = a.c_id
```

**Result**

```
| C_ID | NAME |          EMAIL |    PHONE |   CITY |
----------------------------------------------------
| 8499 | Serj | test@gmail.com | 3-33-333 | London |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8732/3)

Comment: I think OP needs latest email too

Comment: @hop According to the sample in the question, they're hard coding the e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, email in this keys is a non formal key for the table. Someone stupid created this table :)

Comment: @ypercube Looks like `email` is missing.

Comment: That's adding one line: [fiddle-2-for-lazy-prince](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8732/10)

Comment: @PolishPrince . . . You can simplify your `from` clause to:  `(select *
      from ak_contract
      where EmailContacts = 'test@mail.com'
      order by c_id desc
      limit 1)`